# Error in extracting id from sentence to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have an sheet with a column H which contains comments.

I am using the below code, to extract my ID from the comment.

This is successfuly working in almost all the cases.

I dont know, why for a particular row, the extraction is not working.

Could anyone have a look at my code and suggest where i am going wrong.

I have attached an Image which Shows the similar result.

[I have added some samples, if you find in row 3,in this particular case, I am not able to extract the ID from Comment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsEnq.png)

Anylead with this would be helpful .

Below is my code.

```
Sub Cmt()
Dim strLength As Integer
Dim i As Long
For i = 5 To Rows.Count
Dim AllWords As Variant
AllWords = Split(Cells(i, 8).Value, " ")
For Each Item In AllWords
strLength = Len(Item)
If strLength > 0 And strLength <= 13 And Item Like "I5G*?#" Then
Cells(i, 13) = Item
End If
Next
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Go trough the code with `F8` and look what it does.

Comment: @UGP I know what it does, the Problem is just for the particular one row, the ID from the comment is not extracted

Comment: With `F8` you can go trough the code line by line. Hover over the variable or add them to the watch window and you can see the values.

Comment: **Code is working fine for me**. Insead of `Rows.Count` you could use `Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row`, though this will not solve your problem.

Comment: @UGP, Thank yu for the clue,  I found only in that, after the ID immedietly i have an comma ,  I believe,because of this it is not taking that ID alone.

Comment: @Mrig the code is working fine. But now i realised that i have comma end of the id and so, it dint extract the ID. Could you suggest how i can overcome this ?

Comment: @Mrig in the comment it is like, Remarks ID is I2G34586200, good . because of , at the end it dint extract the ID from this particular row. How can I overcome this ?

Comment: Yes because of `"I5G*?#"` the `#` says it has to end on a number, with the comma it does not fufill the requirements. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440632(v=office.12).aspx) for more informations about wildcars.

Comment: Is there any other scenario that could cause the condition to fail? If there are other scenarios as well then code can be made more generic fulfilling all requirements.

Comment: @Mrig i will make an keen Observation and let you know in couple of minutes

Comment: @Mrig, Just the , is the additional criteria. the rest are perfect .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just the , is the additional criteria. the rest are perfect

Below code should handle `,` at the end of `ID 's` assuming that there is just one trailing `,` after `ID 's`

```
Sub Cmt()
    Dim strLength As Integer
    Dim AllWords, Item
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 5 To Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        AllWords = Split(Cells(i, 8).Value, " ")
        For Each Item In AllWords
            strLength = Len(Item)
            If strLength > 0 And strLength <= 13 And Item Like "I5G*?#" Then
                Cells(i, 13) = Item
            ElseIf strLength > 0 And strLength <= 14 And Item Like "I5G*?#," Then
                Cells(i, 13) = Left(Item, strLength - 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: the code is not working Mrig. IT just extracted one ID from the sentence

Comment: @Jenny - Its `i = 5 To Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row` and not `i = 5 To 10`. I edited code now.

Comment: the earlier code, was working in such a way that, anywhere in the column H it finds an ID it was etracting them to the column M. The Id were between the sentence or start of the sentence. The ID is 11 to 13 Digit Long. With this it was working fine. In one row, there is an ID which is 12 Digit Long and , after that. Because of this condition, it failed in this case.

Comment: @Jenny - 12 digit long id followed by a `,` makes length of id to 13 digit which should be true for `strLength <= 13`, so should not be a problem. Else try `strLength <= 14`

Comment: Thank you Mrig, ist working great. I dint notice the for Statement.sorry. but why does it take an ID something like this , I5Gxxxxxxx ? I dont want this from my comment. the ealier code was not recognising this

Comment: @Jenny - You'll have to share `ID's` where its failing condition.

Comment: Also, for some reason, I dint recognise this ID as well I5G1115630100

Comment: you want me to post an Image of it  ? for failing condition ?

Comment: @Jenny - Will be better.

Comment: the comment is like I5Gxxxxxxx Remark - Mandatory, and in the result i got   I5Gxxxxxxx, Which i dont Need to have.

Comment: @ the rest are perfect. No issues now. Just this has failed

Comment: @Jenny - `I5Gxxxxxxx` works well for me. See image I've added in answer.